# {tm_shape}: specify icons via image filenames

Tags: r, dictionary, tmap

I can't assign a separate icon for each point in the CSV file to be displayed as a point

And it looks like this and each point should have a different icon

[image]

```
points <- read.csv("dane_ikony.csv", header = TRUE)
points
points.sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)


for(i in 1:nrow(points)) {
  icon <- tmap_icons(points$Icon[i])
  points.sf$icon[i] <- icon
}


tm_shape(pl.map.sf) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "lightyellow1") +
  tm_shape(points.sf) +
  tm_symbols(shape = icon, size = 1.2, border.lwd = NA) +
  tm_grid(col = "gray",
          labels.size = 0.8) +
  tm_text("Nazwa", size = 0.8, root = F, just = 'top', auto.placement = T) + 
  tm_layout(title = "mapa Polski", 
            legend.text.size = 0.8, 
            legend.title.size = 0.8, 
            frame = TRUE) +
  tm_scale_bar(position = c("left", "bottom"))

tmap_mode("view") 
tm_shape(pl.map.sf) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "lightyellow1") +
  tm_shape(points.sf) +
  tm_text("Nazwa", size = 0.8, root = F, just = 'top', auto.placement = T) + 
  tm_symbols(shape = icon, size = 1.2, border.lwd = NA) +
  tm_view(alpha = 0.5)
```

CSV :

```
x,y,Nazwa,Icon
16.91855,52.40692,Poznan,krakow.png
19.94498,50.06465,Krakow,wroclaw.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To reproduce first download and unzip to `POL_adm` directory the **shapefile** from https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/json/gadm41_POL_1.json.zip. Then load the two required packages.

```R
library(tmap)
library(sf)
```

2. Load the Poland's map.

```R
pl.map.sf <- st_read(dsn = 'POL_adm/gadm41_POL_1.shp')
```

3. Create `cities.csv` file with content as below (or download the file from https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yvdyemr8l3avbu/cities.csv?dl=0).

```R
x,y,Name,Icon
19.94498,50.06465,Krakow,Krakow.png
16.91855,52.40692,Poznan,Poznan.png
21.00762,52.23222,Warszawa,Warszawa.png
17.03044,51.11083,Wroclaw,Wroclaw.png
15.50498,51.93835,ZielonaGora,ZielonaGora.png
```

4. Read the CSV file and convert geographical coordinates to an `sf` object.

```R
points <- read.csv("cities.csv", header = TRUE)
points.sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
```

5. Download 5 **coats of arms** from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3lwew0wcx3y70g/coats_of_arms.zip?dl=0 and save the `5 png` files in the current directory.

```R
list.files(pattern = "png")
[1] "Krakow.png"      "Poznan.png"      "Warszawa.png"   
[4] "Wroclaw.png"     "ZielonaGora.png"
```

6. Create a list of icons with city coats of arms

```R
coats_of_arms = tmap_icons(points.sf$Icon)
```

7. Create the map.

```R
tmap_mode("plot") 
tm_shape(pl.map.sf) +
  ## Pierwsza warstwa
  tm_polygons(col = "lightyellow1") +
  tm_grid(col = "gray", labels.size = 0.8) +
  tm_layout(title = "Map of Poland", 
            legend.text.size = 0.8, 
            legend.title.size = 0.8, 
            frame = TRUE) +
  tm_scale_bar(position = c("left", "bottom")) +
  ## Druga warstwa z nazwami miast i ich herbami
  tm_shape(points.sf) +
  tm_text("Name", col = "blue", size = 1, auto.placement = FALSE) +
  tm_symbols(shape = "Icon", 
             shapes = coats_of_arms, 
             size = 1, 
             border.lwd = NA, 
             ymod = 1) +
  tm_layout(legend.show = FALSE)
```

7. And here is the end result.
   [image: map of Poland]

**!!! IMPORTANT NOTE !!!**

**Is this a bug or is it an intended behaviour?**

It seams that the names of the cities  in the `cities.csv` file **MUST** be listed alphabetically. Otherwise the icons do appear on the map, but in the wrong order (incorrect icons appear next to cities).

Now the order of the names is "from A to Z":

```R
points$Name
[1] "Krakow"      "Poznan"      "Warszawa"    "Wroclaw"     "ZielonaGora"
```

However, after shuffling the data

```R
points <- points[sample(1:nrow(points)), ]
```

the `points` variable may by as below and now the city names are certainly not sorted alphabetically.

```R
         x        y        Name            Icon
5 15.50498 51.93835 ZielonaGora ZielonaGora.png
4 17.03044 51.11083     Wroclaw     Wroclaw.png
1 19.94498 50.06465      Krakow      Krakow.png
3 21.00762 52.23222    Warszawa    Warszawa.png
2 16.91855 52.40692      Poznan      Poznan.png
```

After executing the codes again the map is bad as icons are placed in wrong places Take a close look at the map below and compare it with the previous one. Any suggestions?

[image: map of Poland - BAD]

Comment: The easiest way would be to load the library 
`library(dplyr)`
Then sort the data alphabetically
`arrange(Name)`